# Autostart run_script on start-up of a machine

Tags: linux, boot, autostart

I have a program which is being run using a script manually(i.e. run.sh).

I am planning to make an image (AMI) of the server and launch it at multiple servers.

Before doing that, I should be able to run it without manual intervention, which is, to run the `"run.sh"` script automatically as soon as machine/server starts.

Where should I put this script and what is the process like to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a line in the `/etc/rc.local` file or add a line in `crontab` like this one :

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```