# Easiest Way To Start A Compiled Binary On Boot

Tags: linux, boot, debian-jessie

I compiled a binary from source and to run it for the moment I have to SSH into the server and start it from CLI. I would like to know the easiest way to make it run when the system is booted. I saw a few articles on creating a bash script and placing it in init.d and wonder if there is a better way.

System: Debian Jessie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autostart run\_script on start-up of a machine](http://superuser.com/questions/720030/autostart-run-script-on-start-up-of-a-machine)

Comment: this is not a script but a binary compiled from source without a init.d, below solution solved it and learned another way to complete this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its run as a regular user - just use cron. crontab -e will open up a 'special' text editor instance to edit it. Add a line saying `@reboot foo.sh` and you're good. Ubuntu's wiki has good documentation on [cron as a whole](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) if you want to polish it up as little.

Comment: will @reboot start it when the system starts? thats a good idea, totally forgot about cron

Comment: Yup. And unlike most of the other options, its standard and can be run with regular accounts.

Comment: perfect, will give a try right now and mark your answer

Comment: can I do the path to the binary --varible1 --varible2 without using an bash script? Ive dont quite a lot with cron, but this one is new to me, may have done it before, just not recently so I forget if this will work

Comment: I'd try it. I usually use a bash script simply cause it lets me manage things more easily. You can test with an arbitrary time in the near future.

Comment: worked as needed, marked